# Java Swing with own L&F sometimes suddenly switches back to default L&F

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, default

In a Java Swing application that uses several own UI's (e.g. for JTabbedPane) sometimes right after startup, the Look and Feel (L&F) of the entire application changes back to the default. It quickly shows everything correct and then after a second or less the entire application changes to the ugly default.

Unfortunately, this is difficult to reproduce. It happens very rarely and so far only under Ubuntu when I start it directly from within Eclipse using java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64. I have a newer java version installed too, but I use 1.6 to test compatibility.

Since it happens either for all or for no component, it looks like it does not matter how I I derive the UI. It even changes back this little change where no custom UI is used:

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField();
textField.setBorder(null);
```

So if it happens, then the border will show up.

Since this is difficult to reproduce, I can not give a code example where it always happens. Actually, the one above is already an example, but it does not happen always. But I hope to find someone who run into a similar issue where the L&F or any changes to it suddenly and unwanted changed back to the default. If so, I would appreciate if you could share your experience and hopefully a solution.

---------------- Edit:
I found two workaraounds:

1. For the border problem, I simply use `textField.setBorder(new EmptyBorder());` instead of setting it to null.
2. For the reset of the UI, which was indeed caused by unwanted calls to updateUI, I created for my customized swing objects subclasses that override updateUI(), e.g.:

   ```
   public class JTabbedPaneNoHeads extends JTabbedPane {
       public JTabbedPaneNoHeads() {
           setUI(new GUITabbedPaneNoHeadsUI());
       }

       @Override
       public GUITabbedPaneNoHeadsUI getUI() {
           return (GUITabbedPaneNoHeadsUI) ui;
       }

       @Override
       public void updateUI() {
           /* This was to find out who is calling updateUI:
                       StackTraceElement[] _stackTrace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
                       for (StackTraceElement element : _stackTrace ){
                           System.out.print(element + " -- ");
                       }
                       System.out.println();
           */
           setUI(new GUITabbedPaneNoHeadsUI());
       }
   }
   ```

Now everything works fine.

btw: the calls to updateUI had the following stack trace (generated by the commented block in the code above):

```
livedocket.GUI.design.JTabbedPaneNoHeads.updateUI(JTabbedPaneNoHeads.java:22)
javax.swing.SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI0(SwingUtilities.java:1230)
.... many more of these updateComponentTreeUI0 ...
javax.swing.SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI0(SwingUtilities.java:1245)
javax.swing.SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(SwingUtilities.java:1221)
javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel$AATextListener.updateWindowUI(MetalLookAndFeel.java:2329)
javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel$AATextListener.updateAllUIs(MetalLookAndFeel.java:2342)
javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel$AATextListener.access$200(MetalLookAndFeel.java:2295)
javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel$AATextListener$1.run(MetalLookAndFeel.java:2370)
java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:226)
java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:673)
java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:96)
java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:634)
java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:632)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:108)
java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:643)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:275)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:200)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:190)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:185)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:177)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
```

As I mentioned before, these calls happen only very rarely and only on Java 1.6.

Comment: how do you set the LAF?

Comment: Only by calls to setUI(). E.g. I have my own TabbedPaneUI which is derived from BasicTabbedPaneUI, and I set it for a JTabbedPane t by calling t.setUI(new TabbedPaneUI()).

Comment: that's too brittle: it'll be reset whenever something calls updateUI. Instead, hook your custom ui into the UIManager, f.i. by registering it directly or using a framework that supports custom uis as SwingX plaf

Comment: Good point. This could explain why the ones set by setUI get lost. But why is the setBorder(null) also lost? There I did not use a setUI call.

Comment: @kleopatra: or in other words: would that mean I have to register a new custom UI into the UIManager for any kind of small changes like setBorder(..)? That would be very cumbersome.

Comment: no, basically, first you have to find _why_ your setting is lost - sounds like something calls updateUI after you set the border and that's a bit unusual. As to why your null border isn't kept: LAFs think they can install their own if the property is null (or of type UIResource)

Comment: @kleopatra: This was indeed the reason. I edited my question to show what I now did as solution/workaround. Thank you.

Comment: thanks for the details/workaround :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have seen similar symptoms in an application with threading problems - if I were you I would double-check if all of the GUI is constructed on the Event Dispatch Thread.

Comment: See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: The setup and changes on GUI elements are done on the EDT. But maybe I missed some .. you never know. It will take me a while to go through the entire code. If I find something and this fixes the problem, then I will mark this as answer.

Comment: @Masi: and is UIManager called in EDT?

Comment: @fdregler: Yes, all the setup and changes are done now on the EDT. So it looks like this did not solve the problem.

Comment: @Masi: sorry to hear it. I have no other ideas (other than that it's a bug in JRE, which doesn't really help you much).

Comment: @fdregler: Maybe this is really a bug in the JRE, since it only happens on java version "1.6.0_27", OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.6) (6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.13.04.2) but never on java version "1.7.0_25", OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.10) (7u25-2.3.10-1ubuntu0.13.04.2)